# Web scraping - extracting information from map icons

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I want to scrape the following website.

http://maps.3dhubs.com/

It is a global map with a listing of >7000 suppliers. I want to get the names of all the suppliers. When you zoom into a particular area, you will see the red icons. Clicking on the red icons brings up a pop up which has the name of the supplier on it.

I am using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://maps.3dhubs.com/'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
suppliers = soup.find_all("div", class_="leaflet-popup-pane")
print (suppliers)
driver.quit()
```

The code gives an empty list as output. The information i need is in div tag and leaflet-popup-pane class but this information is only displayed after the icon is clicked.

If this can be done using selenium, please let me know how to do it. In particular, the data (supplier's name) is generated when you click on an icon. I know how to click on text link using selenium but here its an icon and not text.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7In3F.jpg)

Comment: I made a couple of attempts at this put couldn't really get anywhere. The difficulty seems to lie to the icons obscuring each other so the webdriver cannot click on them. I was able to get results from a few hundred of them but it would ultimately result in a crash every time. Maybe there is a better tool to use for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this json file(http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3dhubs/s3fs-public/hubsformap.json) is what you want.I find it in the source of the website.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiM2RodWJzbWFwcyIsImEiOiJBSzBFalRzIn0.j8icvSftfyZ4yxJmEgbrRw';
xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3dhubs/s3fs-public/hubsformap.json'));
```